# Strange blue flashes when using a screen recorder, white flashes when using vlc to record

Tags: cinnamon, ffmpeg, avconv

I use cinnamon currently and whenever I use ffmpeg to record my screen, blue flashes appear when I interact with the cinnamon panel and applets. When I initiate a recording in vlc, similar things happen but with white flashes instead.

Example recording here. http://youtu.be/bx8xhQmiVBk

EDIT: Tweaked the small applet I use to use avconv, produces the exact same effects as well.

```
avconv -f pulse -ac 2 -i alsa_output.pci-0000_00_14.2.analog-stereo.monitor -f x11grab -s 1920x1080 -r 30 -qscale 1  -i :0.0 $HOME/Videos/test2.mkv
```

Comment: Have you checked your display adapter driver, and resolution?

Comment: Yeah, latest stable drivers, nvidia-current. And resolution is at the max my monitor supports, 1080p

Comment: I think I'm having a similar issue right here: 
http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125810/jitter-while-screen-recording-with-avconv